# Greasemonkey Javascript: how to loop through all text and change only whole words?

Tags: javascript, regex, greasemonkey

When I load a web page (which happens to be on Reddit) I want to loop through all visible text, (not tags or attributes or the contents of ), and change one string to another, but whole words only. I'm new to Javascript and Greasemonkey so bear with me. I learn best by looking at code. This code is working but I want to use something like below to store the 'old' strings and 'new' strings. This would make it easier for any user to update the strings. Format: 'old string':'new string'.

```
var arReplacements = {
  "Woman's":"Pink's",
  "woman": "pink",
  "women": "pinks",
  "Woman":"Pink",
  "Women":"Pink",

  "man's": "blue's",
  "Man's":"Blue's",
  "men's":"blue's",
  "Men's":"Blue's",
  "men": "blues",
  "man": "blue",
  "Men": "Blues",
  "Man":"Blue",

  "Girl's":"Pink's",
  "girl's":"pink's",
  "girl": "pink",
  "Girl":"Pink",
  };
```

If you look at my script, I'm changing many strings to other strings, so the regexp has to be built from a variable. Ex:

```
"man" to "blue"
"men" to "blues"
"Man" to "Blue"
"Men" to "Blues"
"man's" to "blue's"
"Man's" to "Blue's"
```

Currently, in function test2(), the old and new words are stored in fromArr[] and toArr[].

INPUT: Many a man has good manners man.

Change 'man' to 'blue'.

EXPECTED OUTPUT: Many a blue has good manners blue. (Note that 'manners' is not changed.)

The current code is here: https://github.com/bulrush15/gmscripts

It is the Changer.user.js file. Code is a bit messy but look at the test2() function, which is running now.

Load this page with Greasemonkey and this script on for testing: https://www.reddit.com/r/test/comments/3kdyfd/test_of_man_and_manners/

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will work with word boundary `\b` and positive look ahead with regex /\bman(?=\b|')/ig

```js
document.write('Many a man has good manners Man Man\'s'.replace(/\bman(?=\b|')/ig, 'blue'));
```

**[Test your Regex here](https://regex101.com/r/vM7rW7/3)**

Comment: Edited my original question to clarify that I'm changing many strings to other strings because the source strings to find are case sensitive.

Comment: What you're doing is changing fixed text, and adding that to the existing HTML document. That's not what I'm looking for. I updated my original post again. I want to be able the user to enter any pair of old and new strings, and all old strings on an existing page on Reddit will change to the new strings, but using whole words only, parts of words will not be changed.

Comment: @Bulrush : you need to do same thing for all of them